# RBAC Implementation

Tags: yii, rbac

In the book "Agile web applications with Yii 1.1 and PHP5 the RBAC is implemented though authassignment and a bizrule. This should support the possibility of granting users with different roles in each project.

but whenever a user is assigned a role in a specific project a new record is added to the authassignment table with this role and that user. since there are 3 roles (owner, member, reader) this does not allow assigning the user to more than 3 projects and the user must be assigned different roles in these projects (otherwise integrity constraint will be violated).

Any ideas? Is this really a flaw in the RBAC implementation in the book?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more of a role for business rules than creating individual roles. For example, a user may be give a particular role that allows them to create and own a project and then a business rule would be used to ensure that only they can administer their project.